# android 9 can't get imei data on system app

Tags: android

I have set `read phone state` permission on manifest.
The app but still can't read IMEI.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


  public void send() {
       final Device activationDevice = DeviceUtil.getInfo(mContext);
        String json = gson.toJson(activationDevice.getImeinumber());
//Log.d("activation","send");
        try {
            volley.post("GetNewActivation", new JSONObject(), new Listener<JSONObject>() {
           ...
        }
    }
```

java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return telephonyManager.getImei();
```

Comment: Please post your code,

Comment: i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei()

Comment: i will test and et you know